# This is a C program to calculate summation of k from 0 to n : nCk . I am getting a segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, math, segmentation-fault

1. the variable test is the number of test cases that follow
2. Function factorial returns the factorial of a number
3. Function summ gives the summation of k from 1 to n nCk

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
float factorial(int x)
{
    if(x==1)
    return 1.0;
    else
    return (x*factorial(x-1));
}
int summ(int y)
{
    int k=1;double sum=0;int r;
    while(k<=y)
    {
        sum=sum +((factorial(y))/(factorial(y-k)*factorial(k)));
        k++;
    }
    r=(int)sum%(int)((1000000007.00));
    return r;
}
main()
{
    int test;
    scanf("%d",&test);int j=0;
    int i=0;int arr[test];int val;int flag;
    while(i<test)
    {
        scanf("%d",&val);
        flag=summ(val);
        arr[i]=flag;
    i++;
    }
    while(j<test)
    {
        printf("%d\n",arr[j] );
        j++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens in factorial function when x = 0?

Comment: Also, what's the range of y and k?  That recursive factorial() routine  will create as many stack frames as the value passed to it--which will certainly crash for any but small values.

Comment: Also, you are applying the modulus function after calculating nCk + sum. You are bound to exceed the integer range. Moreover, you should be using unsigned long long int instead of int for this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a hint, look up the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), which says that

> (n choose 0) + (n choose 1) + ... + (n choose n) = 2<sup>n</sup>

This can be computed in a single line of code using bit shifts.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

in factorial function
     Do
     if(n==1||n==0)
     return 1;
     .....

Answer (score 1):

(nC1 + nC2 + nC3...nCn) = 2^n - 1 using binomial theorum

2^n can be evaluated in O(logn) using fast exponentiation

[Fast Exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

Answer (score 0):

To fix your program, note that when `x = 0`, your function `factorial` will crash, since the recursion goes from 0 to -1, to -2, to -3, etc. Examine your `summ` function, then you can find out that when `k = y`, `factorial(0)` is invoked.

However, to solve your problem in an efficient way, instead of just fixing your program, you should refer to *templatetypedef* 's idea.